# How can I configure Emacs to highlight C++ that violate a detailed code style?

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style

I've been researching existing C++ code style tools and have yet to find any packages which will allow me to highlight sections of a file which break a detailed code style configuration. While there seem to be several options for basic code style settings (what should/shouldn't be indented, line length > some threshold, etc), other issues do not seem to be addressed. For context, I'm hoping to be able to recognize when I do the following:

- { on same line as function definition (should be next line)
- { on next line after if statement (should be same line)
- no space between ) and {
- no space between comparisons (should be a == b instead of a== b,a==b, etc)
- consecutive new lines
- type *var_name or type * var_name instead of type* var_name
- and so on...

This style is heavily enforced on my team, and I am having difficulty minimizing inconsistencies. I'm looking for either an existing emacs tool which allow me to customize these settings extensively, or suggestions on how to create an emacs package myself identifies these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Noufal suggests, Flymake is one option.

Another is [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck). I switched from Flymake to Flycheck a few years ago and haven't looked back. Flycheck supports a large number of languages and tools, and seems to require less hand-holding than Flymake.

From its [GitHub README](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck#features):

> ### Features
>
> - Supports over 30 programming and markup languages with more than 60 different syntax checking tools
> - Fully automatic, fail-safe, on-the-fly syntax checking in background
> - Nice error indication and highlighting
> - Optional error list popup
> - Many customization options
> - A comprehensive manual
> - A simple interface to define new syntax checkers
> - A “doesn't get in your way” guarantee
> - Many 3rd party extensions

For C and C++ code, Flycheck supports [Clang and Cppcheck out of the box](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/languages.html#c-c), and there is a [plugin for Google's C++ style guide](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-google-cpplint) as well.

And of course you can [add your own checkers](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dev/extending.html) if you wish.

Comment: Flycheck seems to be the best option available due to the appearance of more support/use in syntax checking than Flymake. @Chris If you've created your own checkers since switching to Flycheck I would appreciate being able to study some simple examples

Comment: @EJGoogins, I have been well served by the built-in checkers and one or two third-party plugins. The [Google C++ style plugin](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck-google-cpplint/blob/master/flycheck-google-cpplint.el) might be a good example.

Comment: A few years ago?  You must have traveled in time, for Flycheck is less than two years old ;)

Comment: @lunaryorn fair point! I definitely switched pretty early, but I'm not exactly sure when it was. In any case, it's a pretty good tool.

Comment: @Chris Yes, it's my baby, and I'm always really happy when someone likes it!  So thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can configure your tool to emit output in the format that can be understood by [flymake](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Flymake.html), it should be able to do it.

Many tools such as `gcc` itself and others do this so that flymake works.